# Como Seleccionar un ID que cumpla con 2 requisitos en una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Amigos, estoy tratando de resolver que en esta consulta se filtre un cont_cat_cont_id que tenga relación con estos 2 ID 25,32:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cont_cat_cont_id, cont_cat_cat_id 
FROM contents_categorys 
WHERE cont_cat_cat_id IN (25, 32)
```

Que me devuelve estos valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito filtrar en la tabla cont_cat_cont_id los 9 por ejemplo porque se repite tanto en cont_cat_cat_id 32 y en la cont_cat_cat_id 16;

Respuesta esperada que solo muestre estas dos filas:

9 | 25

9 | 32

Intenté con INNER JOIN pero me da error, intenté con UNION pero no me filtra bien.

```
SELECT  cont_cat_cont_id AS OBJ_ID1
    FROM @tmp contents_categorys
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  cont_cat_cont_id AS OBJ_ID2
                FROM @tmp
                WHERE cont_cat_cat_id  IN ('35','25')
        ) Casos
        ON Casos.OBJ_ID2 = contents_categorys.OBJ_ID1
    WHERE cont_cat_cat_id IN ('25')
```

Intente algo asi, pero me da error

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes poner una imagen de la estructura de tus tablas, y mostrar que error obtienes ?

Comment: No es un error en si, necesito ver una posible solución, de como filtrarlos, necesito que me devuelva los que cumplen con esas 2 categorias, y llegue a esa consulta que filtra, pero me falta que no muestro los otros.

Comment: No entendí tu planteamiento: *se repite tanto en cat 32 y en la 16*. ¿A qué hace referencia el `16`?

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos que intentas ? y como lo intentas ? para darnos una idea

Comment: Si esas categorias estan relacionadas en 32 y 25, necesito filtrar el cont_cat_cont_id que cumpla con ambas categorias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de lograr lo que quieres sería agrupando las filas repetidas de `cont_cat_cat_id` en una sola fila/columna mediante [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) combinado con [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)  y verificando que esté más de una vez con [`HAVING COUNT(*)`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx).

La única diferencia aquí es que tendrás una sola fila por grupos de resultados.

La consulta sería esta:

```
SELECT 
    cont_cat_cont_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(cont_cat_cat_id) AS cont_cat_cat_id
FROM contents_categorys
    WHERE cont_cat_cat_id in (25,32)
    GROUP BY cont_cat_cont_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Te dejo aquí un fiddle completo.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE contents_categorys (
  cont_cat_cont_id INT,
  cont_cat_cat_id INT
  
);
INSERT INTO contents_categorys (cont_cat_cont_id,cont_cat_cat_id) VALUES (8,32);

INSERT INTO contents_categorys (cont_cat_cont_id,cont_cat_cat_id) VALUES (9,25);

INSERT INTO contents_categorys (cont_cat_cont_id,cont_cat_cat_id) VALUES (9,32);

INSERT INTO contents_categorys (cont_cat_cont_id,cont_cat_cat_id) VALUES (10,32);

INSERT INTO contents_categorys (cont_cat_cont_id,cont_cat_cat_id) VALUES (12,25);

INSERT INTO contents_categorys (cont_cat_cont_id,cont_cat_cat_id) VALUES (12,32);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    cont_cat_cont_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(cont_cat_cat_id) AS cont_cat_cat_id
FROM contents_categorys
    WHERE cont_cat_cat_id in (25,32)
    GROUP BY cont_cat_cont_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

| cont_cat_cont_id | cont_cat_cat_id |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 25,32 |
| 12 | 25,32 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xa7Zq2YdPhnZGe13wrKPBb/0)

Comment: Aunque no se ve como la respuesta que quiere el OP, no conocía que eso se pudiese hacer con GROUP_CONCAT, esta genial !

Comment: Ahh gracias :D, de verdad

Comment: @MateoGuio `GROUP_CONCAT()` es muy útil cuando quieres poner juntas varias columnas en una consulta de agrupación.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo después de intentar con varias consultas y replicar tu tabla, genere una consulta que me devuelve el resultado que quieres. Creo que la consulta no necesita explicación es bastante simple, quedo atento:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cont_cat_cont_id,cont_cat_cat_id FROM contents_categorys WHERE cont_cat_cont_id = 9;
```

Dejo la imagen de la tabla y la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, pero la respuesta correcta es de @A. Cedano, porque en este filtro sabes el valor de 9, que podian hacer luego una subconsulta, pero A.Cenado, lo hizo en una gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Con gusto amigo :D

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from contents_categorys 
where cont_cat_cont_id in (
                           select cont_cat_cont_id
                           from contents_categorys
                           group by cont_cat_cont_id   
                           having count(*) = (select count(*)
                                              from contents_categorys
                                              group by cont_cat_cat_id
                                              order by desc count(*)
                                              limit 1)
                          )
```

La **subconsulta** más interna:

```
select count(*)
from contents_categorys
group by cont_cat_cat_id
order by desc count(*)
limit 1
```

cuenta cuantas veces aparece el registro que más se repite atendiendo al **campo cont_cat_cat_id** (esta **subconsulta** devuelve un número), sobre este resultado aplicamos una consulta que nos va a devolver el registro que se repite la misma cantidad de veces que el resultado que devuelve la **subconsulta más interna** pero esta vez atendiendo al **campo cont_cat_cont_id** para ello usamos la **cláusula having** que es como un **where** pero a nivel de grupos. Finalmente ejecutamos una **consulta general** que nos va a devolver todos los campos siempre y cuando el **campo cont_cat_cont_id** de esta **consulta más general** esté incluido en el resultado devuelto por la **segunda subconsulta**.